# How to show heading direction from Current location to other location on map in ios?

Tags: ios, dictionary, cllocation

I have a requirement where i have to show the heading direction towards any location on map from user current location. Let say if we have 4 location annotation on map apart from current location and i want to show heading towards any of the location after tapping on it.
How can we achieve it. I have gone trough Map API documentation & Locaiotn API, I found that we get the heading value in the delegate method which provided by API when we called the startupdatingheading method. I not getting idea how can we externally get the heading data between two locations.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show route direction between 2 location? If yes then you can call default map application to do the same. You need to create MapItems and pass to default map application.

Comment: @TechNet-Weblineindia Thanks for your reply.Not route direction, I am looking for to show heading direction pointing towards any location from current location.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18961856/771231

Comment: On the surface of a sphere, as earth is one, the heading will change with the distance. How far are your locations typically apart?

Comment: Locations have near about 50 km distance ? But i am wondering what does it make effect on the heading ?

Comment: With a given distance, the compass bearing towards a destination is constant, sorry, I did not want to confuse you. As you get closer to the destination, the bearing towards it will change, because in essence you are following a section through a sphere.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer below?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the initial bearing to get from lat1,lon1 to lat2,lon2 on a straight line.

```
double lat1=48.0;  // source latitude, example data
double lon1=17.0;  // source longitude

double lat2=49.0;  // destination latitude
double lon2=18.0;  // destination longitude

double lat1Rad = lat1 * M_PI / 180;
double lat2Rad = lat2 * M_PI / 180;

double dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * M_PI / 180;

double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2Rad);
double x = cos(lat1Rad) * sin(lat2Rad) - sin(lat1Rad) * cos(lat2Rad) * cos(dLon);

double bearingRad = atan2(y, x);

// this is the bearing from source to destination in degrees, normalized to 0..360
double bearing = fmod((bearingRad * 180 / M_PI + 360),360);
```