# iOS MKMapView set rotation to user course / direction

Tags: ios, rotation, mkmapview, direction, heading

I want to rotate the Map of my MKMapView component to the direction the user is walking/driving.

I don't want that the map is centered and zoomed automatically. Thats the reason why I don't use `setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`.

I tried to use the heading of location updates and call the setTransform method of the mapView:

```
- (void)headingUpdate:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    [self.mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * newHeading.magneticHeading * M_PI / 180)];
}
```

The problem is that the whole view (not only the content / map) itself is rotated, see screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea? I only want to set the direction the user is walking (no zooming, centering etc.)

Comment: My answer here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936839/programatically-rotating-a-mkmapview-in-ios7